# How Do I get the int representation of a Big Field in SAGE

Tags: field, sage

I am trying to get the int representation of a Big Field in SAGE using int_repr. Specifically, GF(2^80) but I get the error below. My, natural question is, How Do I get the int representation of a Big Field in SAGE?

```
K = GF(2^80,"t")
(K.random_element()).int_repr()

'sage.rings.finite_rings.element_ntl_gf2e.FiniteField_ntl_gf2eElement' object has no attribute 'int_repr'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug/unimplemented behavior](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/8578).